# Is correct how I rotate my UINavigationBar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, rotation, uinavigationbar

I have a simple UIViewController where in the viewDidLoad I have:

```
_navigationBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
[self.view addSubview:_navigationBar];

_toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 416, 320, 44)];   
[self.view addSubview:_toolbar];
```

In the didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation I put:

```
_navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44);
```

And it works but I don't like very much the effect which it did. Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You supposed to set the appropriate autoresizingMask for each view when initializing it rather than changing its frame/bounds/position manually when the view rotates. 
Doing so, the view rotation will make its subviews to be resized (adjusted) automatically.

for example:

```
[navigationBar setAutoResizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
```

or you can combine various [UIViewAutoresizing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/autoresizingMask) masks using | operator.
This property does the same thing that IB when you adjust the springs in each view (In the inspector window)